# Migration could not be done undefined method `apply_schema=` for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting this error while running `rake db:migrate`

```
rake db:migrate                          
rake aborted!
undefined method `apply_schema=' for Devise:Module
/home/dexter/Desktop/Triton/config/initializers/devise.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

I have checked devise.rb

```rb
# Automatically apply schema changes in tableless databases
config.apply_schema = false
```

devise users model

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
       t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
       t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Encryptable
      # t.string :password_salt

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
       t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
       t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
       t.datetime :locked_at

      ## Token authenticatable
      # t.string :authentication_token

      t.string :user_name
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :user_type
      t.string :about


      t.timestamps
    end

      add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
      add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
      add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end
end
```

Comment: May the link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610919/devise-new-errors-encrytable

Comment: i tried but still the same

Comment: comment the line and give it a shot again

Comment: when i commented this line ( apply_schema) it raises another undefined method , commenting line is not a solution

Comment: What another exception? You may want to make sure it's not just another issue, as I suspect that there were two removed methods in the upgrade which removed `apply_schema`.